# Change URL parameters with jQuery based on a checkbox options

Tags: jquery, asp.net, href, checkboxlist

I am new to jQuery but I have a situation that I need to alter an existing anchor tag parameters from a checkbox list.

So I have an

```
<a href="defatul.aspx?nOp=1&name=Jack&place=A">Link</a>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbOptions" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="A">Place A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="B">Place B</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="C">Place C</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I would like for the LINK 's parameters to change dynamically when the user selects a checkbox option.

So if the user selected "Place C" the href URL would change to defatul.aspx?nOp=1&name=Jack&place=C automatic.

I assume this can be completed within jQuery.  I have searched but cannot find examples of being able to accomplish this.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a form submission with the GET method? This is how ASPX pages are typically passed parameters, especially from form inputs. You don't need jQuery to do this, just basic HTML. If you need other parameters in the form submission URL, use hidden input fields.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myselect").on("change", function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

        if (selectedValue == "A") {
            $("#mylink").attr("href", "default.aspx?sel=A");
        } else if (selectedValue == "B") {
            $("#mylink").attr("href", "default.aspx?sel=B");
        } else if (selectedValue == "C") {
            $("#mylink").attr("href", "default.aspx?sel=C");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<a id="mylink" href="default.aspx?nOp=1&name=Jack&place=A">Link</a>
<select id="myselect">
<option value="A">Place A</option>
<option value="B">Place B</option>
<option value="C">Place C</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

To add some explanation as well... Hookup the change event of the dropdown when the document fully loads.  In that event, get the value of the dropdown, and change the href attribute of the hyperlink according to your needs.  Hopefully that helps get you going.

Edit: Sorry, just noticed you need it for a checkbox list.  I will adjust shortly.

Edit 2: I'm not sure the example works with checkboxes, since you could have multiple checked.  Let me know if you need any additional help.